# Complicated join query

Tags: sql, join

I was originally doing this through four separate queries - I think it's time I optimize my code through the use of joins...

I have four tables (as shown below):

```
[sl_student_course]
student_id (int 11)
------------------
course_id (int 11)
------------------

[sl_project_course]
project_id(int 11)
------------------
course_id (int 11)
------------------

[sl_project]
project_id (int 11) - Primary Key -
_____________________
professor_id (int 11)
---------------------
project_name (varchar 50)

[sl_professor]
professor_id(int 11) - Primary Key -
_____________________
professor_name (varchar 50)
---------------------
project_email (varchar 50)
```

**What information do I need?**

I need all data from `sl_project` and `sl_professor` where `sl_student_course.course_id` = `sl_project_course.course_id` AND then I need to use the `project_id` from `sl_project_course`

**SO...**

`sl_student_course.course_id` --> `sl_project_course.project_id` --> `sl_project.professor_id`, `sl_project.project_name`, --> `sl_professor.professor_name`, `sl_professor.professor_name`

**Does this make any sense?**

- If it doesn't, here's another example!

```
sl_student_course
course_id |  1

sl_project_course
project_id | 1
course_id  | 1

sl_project
project_id | 1
professor_id | 2
project_name | project1

sl_professor
professor_id | 2
professor_name | John Doe
professor_email | John@Doe.com
```

Comment: Do you want all of this information for a given project ID?

Comment: Yes, I want projectName, professorName,professorEmail, where the course_id and the project_id match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoping I understood your table relationships correctly, which has professors joined to projects (in the sl_project table).

This will get you project and professor data (using TSQL):

```
SELECT P.project_name, F.professor_name, F.professor_email
FROM sl_project P
    INNER JOIN sl_professor F ON F.professor_id = P.professor_id

    -- Not sure where course is coming into play, since you aren't selecting
    -- anything from the students/course table, but if you need to ensure there is a
    -- course for this project and students in the course, these joins are necessary.
    INNER JOIN sl_project_course C ON C.project_id = P.project_id
    INNER JOIN sl_student_course S ON S.course_id = C.course_id
WHERE P.project_id = @project_id
```

Comment: Ok, I have a few questions...

1.How does the query know what "P" and "F" are if you are declaring them LATER in the query?
2. Why are you using "inner" join vs. "natural" join?
3. What does the "@" sign represent / do in this query?

Comment: A [natural join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join) compares the values of any and all columns that happen to have the same name, which is discouraged.  Better to make the joining column(s) explicit.  The query knows what P and F are because I'm aliasing them in the FROM/JOIN.  SQL is smart enough to figure out whats what even though they are 'declared' later in the query.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty impressive - sql is smarter than I thought! I read that the "@" symbol represents a parameter query, however, if that were the case wouldn't you need to give the parameter a value somewhere? I'm assuming the query knows we're referencing `sl_project` when we say "@project_id" because it's so smart again?

Comment: @Evan: The database access module of your programming language should replace the @-var with the real value of some variable. Usually you use query.bind('project_id', 42). Avoids SQL injections.

Comment: @j13r This query worked without me binding anything though - that is why I'm so confused. It somehow knew which table the query was referring to.

Comment: What did it select? Did it use NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
 select sl_project.project_name, sl_professor.professor_name, sl_professor.professor_email 
 from sl_student_course
 natural join sl_project_course
 natural join sl_project
 natural join sl_professor
```

The natural join is nice because it prefers convention over configuration -- so if you do your db design in the expected way, you safe effort.

Update: replaced * by specific fields requested.

Comment: Wouldn't that just select all fields from sl_stduent_course then?

Comment: @Evan: A join returns all fields from both sides of the join, so j13r's query would return all fields from all four tables. (Relational algebra has concepts of "semi-joins" and "anti-joins" that get fields only from one side of the join, but SQL doesn't support those directly.) That said, I don't really recommend `natural join`; I think it's better to explicitly specify the join condition.

Comment: So, ruakh, what would you do then? Inner join?